# Databricks- How to drop tables when underlying storage account pointing to the mount location is removed?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

Sequence of events:

1. Created external tables in databricks using mount location.
2. Azure Storage account pointing to the mount location of the external tables is deleted.
3. Getting error while dropping tables as well as schema.

What should be the approach to delete such tables or schema?

Tried unmount and drop tables or schema but not feasible as there were lot of mount locations created.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced your scenario and it's working fine for me.

Follow   the below steps:

Created mount point to the azure Storage account

[image]

Created external tables in databricks using mount location.

[image]

Azure Storage account pointing to the mount location of the external tables is deleted.

[image]

dropping tables with azure Storage account pointing to the mount location.

[image]